# Не находит файл в jar classpath

Tags: java, файлы, classloader

Скомпилировал программу. В самом корне `classpath` лежит файл.

Работаю в IDEA и файл находит, но вот в скомпиленном не хочет.

Путь к файлу получается такой: `file:\D:\Program.jar!\file.json`

И пишет что не может его найти.

Получаю файл через: `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()`

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: попробуйте прямой слэш.

Answer (score 0):

```
URL resource = getClass()
                 .getClassLoader()
                 .getResource("/file.json");
```

Comment: а я разве не так делаю? URL получается null

Comment: Если возвращается null, значит в корне jar-файла нет этого файла. Проверьте, что IDEA его упаковывает.

Comment: проверял. открывал jar файл - он там был

Comment: @Tsyklop попробуйте без первого слеша, просто `"file.json"`

Comment: @AlexChermenin и так и так пробовал.

Comment: Исходник и jar-файл куда-нибудь выложить можете?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev к сожалению нет. Платный проект.

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь работать со внешним файлом как с ресурсом. Ресурс - это файл, который **всегда** находится в classpath, но внешний файл там не находится или, как в вашем случае, находится там не всегда. Судя по всему вы скопировали его во временную директорию, которую использует ваш IDE для хранения `*.class` файлов и поэтому являющуюся временным classpath. Пока вы в IDE это работает, но внутрь Jar ваш файл не попадает. Вам надо либо работать с файлом как просто с файлом (например через `FileInputStream`), либо положить его в ресурсы (в директорию `src/main/resources`), после чего он окажется внутри Jar и тогда ваш старый код всегда сможет его найти.